# Postgre Group by amount intervals

Tags: sql, postgresql, integer, intervals

So I have a table with, for example, products with their prices. The price goes from 1$ till 15 000$. So i would like to count the amount of products in each 1000$ interval. Basically, I would like to know how many products costs more than 0 and less then 1000$, how many costs more than 1000$ less than 2000$.
I know how to do the same with time, but not with the amounts
The result should look like

```
Interval    Amount
1000        5
2000        4
3000        8
...         ...
14000       6
15000       8
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is aggregation with some math:

```
select ceil(amount / 1000) * 1000 as amt_group, count(*)
from t
group by amt_group
order by amt_group;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT round(price,-3), count(*) FROM prices GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```